# VS 2015 Где хранится код добавленный в ToolBox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Используется**
VS 2015

Через Ctrl+V добавил фрагмент кода в ToolBox.

В какой папке сохраняется фрагменты кода, которые находятся в ToolBox?

**Рисунок**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]